# Graph API assigned label filtering

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm making a graph API call the following way: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_ID}/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group$select=id,displayname,createdDateTime,assignedLabels&$count=true&$filter=assignedLabels/any(label : label/displayName eq 'TEST')`

In essence I'm trying to fetch all the groups that contain the label "Test"

What I would expect to get back as a reply is this:

"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups(id,displayName,createdDateTime,assignedLabels)",

```
"value": [
    {
        "id": "[GUID]",
        "displayName": "TEST",
        "createdDateTime": "2023-02-04T15:24:05Z",
        "assignedLabels": [
            {
                "labelId": "[GUID]",
                "displayName": "TEST"
            }
        ]
    }
```

However I'm getting the following reply back:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported query on property 'AssignedLabel'.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2024-01-31T15:31:13",
        "request-id": "8f3de165-3c0b-4ff2-84ac-95f0ab042227",
        "client-request-id": "8f3de165-3c0b-4ff2-84ac-95f0ab042227"
    }
}
}
```

Any idea why this filter operation is invalid?

Tried to make filtering as usually do with arrays using the any expression.

Comment: Your filter is correct, but filtering on assignedLabels is not supported by Graph API.